# Running a project with shell commands

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, perl, nlp

I need to open a project which I think it is written in linux or need linux env for building it. 
I use Win8 and I'mnot familiar with Linux env anymore.
Iin it's  README file, it is written s.th like this:

```
HOW TO INSTALL
> tar  xzvf  DepOE-beta.tar.gz
> sh install-DepOE.sh

Two NLP tools are installed: 
- DepPattern (dependency-based parser)
- Tree-Tagger (PoS tagger)

Pay attention: do not install the package in a directory whose name contain blank spaces!

HOW TO USE
depOE.sh  <tagger> <lang> <file> [parser]

      tagger=freeling, treetagger
      language=gl, es, en, pt, fr
      file=path of the input file
```

I opened it by Eclipse env which is integrated with Perl. but I couldnt open it.

[image]

what should I do??
please help me:(

Comment: It might work to install cygwin and follow the readme steps. https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: install virtualbox > install a linux dist. > go to shell > follow the instructions

Comment: the extension sh means it is a bash file. You might execute it with cygwin, as it inlcludes sh and most gnu/linux tools. Maybe you can post the content of the installation file.

Answer (score 2):

since the usage file specifically says that you need to run

```
depOE.sh  <tagger> <lang> <file> [parser]
```

I believe you will need some sort of UNIX shell to make it work. Moreover from the file tree you posted I believe you will also need a running Perl implementation on your machine. Please refer to http://slu.livejournal.com/17395.html for a tutorial on how to install Cygwin and Perl for Windows. Cygwin should give you some basic Linux/Unix/GNU tools for Windows environments and Perl obviously is a Perl interpreter for Windows.

However, I believe in your case the option to run a real Linux operating system in a virtual environment (if you want to keep your Windows installation untouched) is the best way to go. The fastest way (and a free option) would be to download VirtualBox from https://www.virtualbox.org and a Linux VM for instance with Ubuntu preinstalled from here http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/.

Comment: Thanks, now I downloaded VirtualBox and installed it,I downloaded ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386 from the site you mentioned before, when I extracted it contains two files called ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386 and ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386 which are Virtual Disk Image (.vdi) type.
I dont know how can I use it with virtualbox and finally install Linux, all of install tutorials are by .iso file! 
I really confused, plz help me:(

Comment: In Virtual Box create a new virtual machine (select processor and memory that suits your needs) and when the wizard comes to the stage of selecting a virtual disk image (hard drive) do not go with the available defaults but select the downloaded VDI file.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I think I could open it!

Comment: I'm really sorry for disturbing you, but when I type the installation command in Ubuntu terminal, they aren't executed. even when I type cd /d command I cant access my drives, please help me:(

Comment: Of course, you need to copy the data inside the virtual machine first. I suggest you use some sort of cloud service to do that. The hard drives of your host machine are generally not available to the virtual machine.